# How can I use a Html.DropDownListFor without a lambda expression?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code that works:

```
@for (var index = 0; index < Model.AdminSummaries.Count(); index++) {

   <div class="rep_td0" id="rk_@(index)">
      @Model.AdminSummaries[index].RowKey
   </div>
   <div class="rep_td0"> 
   @Html.DropDownListFor(
      x => x.AdminSummaries[index].Status, 
      new SelectList(
            AdminStatusReference.GetAdminStatusOptions(),
            "Value",
            "Text",
      ), 
      new { id = string.Format("Status_{0}", index) }
   )
```

I iterate through Model.AdminSummaries which is a type of

```
public IList<AdminSummary> AdminSummaries { get; set; }
```

As it is an IList I can use the indexing and x => x.AdminSummaries[index].Status works to get the correct status for each row and there's also an index number that I can use to change the id of items for each row.

Now I have a problem. I want to apply the same code method to the following which is a class in my model with similar fields to AdminSummaries (including a Status field):

```
public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

As it is an ICollection I think I cannot access elements using the [index]

I can use a foreach but HOW can I supply the status value to the first parameter of DropDownListFor? Also how can I get an index value so I can index the fields in the rows.

**Update**

The index point was something I added to the original question. Important that the solution can do something like the following so I can use jQuery on form fields later.

```
id="rk_@(index)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an editor template. So you replace this for loop with the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Items)
```

and then you define the editor template which will be rendered automatically for each element of the collection (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Item.cshtml`):

```
@model Item
<div class="rep_td0"> 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SomePropertyOfItemToBindTo, 
        new SelectList(
            AdminStatusReference.GetAdminStatusOptions(),
            "Value",
            "Text",
            Model.SomePropertyOfItemToBindTo
        )
    )
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution looks very clean indeed. Just one thing. I also need to be able to access a count as there are some items that use the count. For example: <div class="rep_td0" id="rk_@(index)">@Model.AdminSummaries[index].RowKey</div>  I will try to explain this in the question as I can't really show it well here.

Comment: I added something to the original question. Not sure if I should open a new question for this. Just let me know. I want to be fair.

Comment: @Samantha2, what exactly do you need to do with jQuery later on those fields? There might be an easier way.

Comment: If a user clicks on one field then I want to get the row value of that field and then use that row ID to read the value of another field on the same row.

Comment: @Samantha2, the id of the field currently contains only the index, not some real unique identifier. If you wanted to get the index of the DOM element within some matched elements this is still possible with jQuery. You don't need to assign the id field at all.